# libiconv-1.14-iconv-fix-inline.patch on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

Hello I try to patch libiconv and I get this error. What should I do?

[root@localhost ~]# patch -Np0 -i libiconv-1.14-iconv-fix-inline.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

### The text leading up to this was:

|--- lib/iconv.c.orig   2015-08-01 20:34:47.018022800 +0100

### |+++ lib/iconv.c        2015-08-01 20:35:06.783246600 +0100

File to patch: libiconv-1.14-iconv-fix-inline.patch
patching file libiconv-1.14-iconv-fix-inline.patch
Hunk #1 FAILED at 176.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file libiconv-1.14-iconv-fix-inline.patch.rej

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what are you trying to achieve. Are you re-compiling libiconv? Have you got the actual libiconv source?